# Unity - Ошибка при сборке игры

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Когда я компилирую свою игру для платформы Windows, Linux или Android, некоторые функции теряются, но во время процесса компиляции ошибок нет. Примеры потерянной функциональности - не работают некоторые триггеры. Инвентарь не обновляется. В редакторе все отлично работает.

[image: Тригнер входа в сундук]

Comment: Это что-то вроде "тыжпрограммист, помоги"? Приложите код, опишите, что за функции. Unity писали не идиоты, и у них же все работает? Вероятно, вы допустили ошибку в коде, а выглядит это так, как будто что-то не работает.

Comment: Проблема в том, что когда я компилирую свою игру для платформы Windows, Linux или Android, некоторые функции теряются, но во время процесса компиляции ошибок нет.

Примеры потерянной функциональности - не работают некоторые триггеры. Инвентарь не обновляется. В редакторе все отлично работает.

Comment: Так покажите пример того, что не работает.

Comment: [ссылка](https://ibb.co/jddG1o) В едиторе когда подходите к сундуку можно справа увидеть кнопку.

Comment: Простите. И что я тут должен видеть? Что фон поменялся? Кнопки нет? Если вам кажется, что не работает функция, то покажите ее код. (Желательно обновить пост, а не прилагать код ссылкой на pastebin)